# On screen text validation using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have test one web based application using selenium, which comes with some animation. That animation's conversation(cc text) will comes in a web element area.

Each on screen text time interval is different. Then how to verify this text using selenium web-driver.

Comment: Can you share link as issue is not quite clear?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: It looks like you could use [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html)